# Cannot find bean definition , should I annotate an interface too?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3

I have an interface as show below

```
   public interface UserManager {

      void insertUser(User user);
   .......
```

Now I have an implementation class as below

```
@Service
public class UserManagerImpl implements UserManager {

    @Autowired
    private UserDAO userDAO;
```

In my controller

```
@Controller
public class ExampleGizmoController {

    @Autowired
    private UserManager userManager;
```

UserDAOImpl is

```
@Service
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
```

My application-context.xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.foo" />
```

which scans all my packages.I have deployed it as war file and when the deployment happens,
The userManager property is not getting autowired to the ExampleGizmoController and shows the error in tomcat as below

```
Spring-MVC threw load() exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No qualifying bean of type [com.foo.UserManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean
which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I was able to make out that autowiring was not happening , even though it was annotation driven and component scanning is turned on. Is there anything else I should do for autowiring to work ?

Comment: are all the classes in com.foo package ?

Comment: yes , all classes are in com.foo package , so the component scanning works.

Comment: And what about `UserDAO`?Do you have correct implementation of this interface?

Comment: @PetrMensik yes , I have added the UserDAOImpl class snippet in the question.

Comment: What I found from googling around is that you need to annotate your class with corresponding roles,but I am already doing that.I have already annotated UserManager with @Component. Still autowiring doesnt happen.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

is also required in your config file

Comment: does it have to do anything with bean autowiring ? its for MVC right ? I have added  <mvc:annotation-driven/> too , but did not post here. Still the same exception.

Comment: if you have that, everything looks good, are you sure everything is com.foo ? Do your logs say anythign else ?

Comment: yes its com.foo , logs points to the same thing "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's stupid... but try to remove implements UserManager from UserManager Impl ..

Comment: I will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Service("userManager")`. Its a way of telling Spring that you want to name your `UserManagerImpl` bean instance with "userManager".

Answer (score 0):

Same error i faced, but i've got one more dao class which retrieves information of user manager. You should add @Repository annotation to dao class.
Your another dao class looks like that;

```
@Repository("userManagerDao")
public class UserManagerDAOImpl implements UserManagerDao{
    public UserManagerDTO createNewUserManager() {
        UserManagerDTO userManager = new UserManagerDTO();
        userManager.setId(1);
        userManager.setFirstName("First Name");
        userManager.setLastName("Last Name");
        return userManager;
    }
}
```